# Making a column having an "unique" value depending on the value of another column

Tags: sql, relational-database

Let's say I have this simple table called "characters":

```
realm_id | character_name | xp
---------|----------------|----------
       1 |     "mike"     | 10
       1 |     "lara"     | 25
       2 |     "mike"     | 40
```

What I want to do is to have **unique** names depending on the `realm_id`. So, for example, while having two `"mikes"` with **different** `realm_id`s is allowed, it's **not** allowed to have two `"mikes"` within the same `realm_id`. Is that possible?

Comment: In Sql Server starting from 2008, you can use a filtered index, don't know about the rest of database engines

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: create unique index (realm_id, name)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to perform a SELECT statement on this data then you'll be looking for something like this (assuming highest XP wins);

```
SELECT
realm_id
character_name
MAX(XP) AS XP
FROM characters
```

However, if you want the table to not allow duplicates in the first place then you're best looking at making teh realm_id and character_name a composite primary key. That will stop your duplication happening in the first place although you'll have to consider what happens when somebody tries to insert that duplicate, it'll throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Create a primary key on the table that consists of realm_id and character_name.  The primary key will enforce uniqueness in the table across realm and character.  Thus, you could have realm_id=1, character_name='Mike' and realm_id=2, character_name='Mike', but if you tried to insert realm_id=1 and character_name='Mike' again, the insert would fail.  Your uniqueness is guaranteed.